# Finding the $100$-th term of $1,3,4,9,10,12,13\dots$ (powers of $3$, or sums of distinct powers of $3$)

Tags: sequences-and-series

> The increasing sequence $1,3,4,9,10,12,13\dots$ consists of all positive integers which are power of $3$ or sums of distinct powers of $3$. Find the $100$-th term of this sequence.

Comment: What's a hundred in base $2$?

Comment: @Lord Shark the Unknown: Bet you think that you are clever. Well, you are. So there!

Answer (score 1):

Try this question first: how many numbers can be derived with $3^i$ for $i$ from $0$ to $n$ using the way described in OP? Or a different but very similar question how many such numbers are there that are less then $3^n$

You have

$3^0, 3^1, 3^2, \cdots, 3^n$

The nature of the numbers present in the sequence determines that however you pick numbers from it, a different combination (of the numbers you picked) will result in a different sum. For each number in the sequence, you either pick it or leave it. So numbers derived from the sequence, including numbers already in it, are $2^n-1$, minus $1$ because we are not allow to picking no numbers at all.

This is what  Lord Shark the Unknown meant by the binary representation of 100.

\begin{align}
\text{Seq}\hspace{1cm} &\text{Binary} & n\text{th Number}&\\
1\hspace{1cm}& 1& 1\hspace{0.5cm}&\\
2\hspace{1cm}& 10 &3\hspace{0.5cm}& \text{bin.rep 1 with 1 trailing zero}=3^1\\
3\hspace{1cm}& 11 &4\hspace{0.5cm}& \\
4\hspace{1cm}& 100 &9\hspace{0.5cm}& \text{bin.rep. 1 with 2 trailing zero} =3^2\\
5\hspace{1cm}& 101 &10\hspace{0.5cm}& 10=9+1\\
6\hspace{1cm}& 110 &12\hspace{0.5cm}& \text{binary 100+binary 10, sum of corresponding numbers } 9+3=12\\
7\hspace{1cm}& 111 &13\hspace{0.5cm}& \text{binary 100+binary 11, sum of corresponding numbers }9+4=13\\
8\hspace{1cm}& 1000 &27\hspace{0.5cm}& \text{binary rep 1 with 3 trailing zero}=3^3\\
\end{align}

$100=64+32+4=2^6+2^5+2^2$ so the number you are looking at is $3^6+3^5+3^2$

This technique also applies if a different base is used.

Answer (score 1):

It's clear the numbers are:

$1, 3, 3^2, 3^3, .....$

$1+3, 1+ 3^2, 1 + 3^3, ...$

$1 + 3 +3^2, 1 + 3 + 3^2,....$

the only issue is what order do we put them in?

The thing to note is that we can't have anything $+ 3^k$ until we have $3^k$ first and $1 + 3 + 3^2 + .... + 3^k < 3^{k+1}$ so we must got through everything $+ 3^k$ before we can get to $3^{k+1}$.

So we have a  rather recursive pattern.

$k = 0$; First term: $1$

$k = 1$;Term 2-3; $3; 3+1$

$k = 2$; Term 4-7: $3^2; 3^2 + 1; 3^2 + 3; 3^2 + 3 + 1$

$k = 3$; Term 8-15: $3^3; 3^3 + 1; 3^3 + 3; 3^3 + 3 + 1; 3^3 + 3^2; 3^3 + 3^2 + 1; 3^3 + 3^2 + 3; 3^3 + 3^2 + 3 + 1$.

....etc.

So of the group $k=k$ we have stuff $+3^k$ and the "stuff" can be for each $0\le i < k$ that we either add $3^i$ or .. we don't. So there are $2^{k}$ in the $k$ group.  And $2^{k-1}$ in the $k-1$ group.

And before the $k$th group we have $1 + 2 + 2^2 + ... + 2^{k-1} =2^k - 1$ terms. So the $k$th group starts and $2^k$ and goes to for $2^k$ terms to end at $2^k + (2^k -1) = 2^{k+1} -1$.

And we stuff the $k$ group in order of fitting the subgroups of lower values than $k$ in them first.

$3^k, 1+3^k, 3+3^k, 1+3 + 3^k , 3^2 + 3^k, etc;$

And each sum in the $k$ group is of the form $b_0*1 + b_1*3 + b_2*3^2 + ..... + b_{k-1}*3^{k-1} + 3^k; b_i = \{0,1\}$ with the $b_0*1 + b_1*3 + b_2*3^2 + ..... + b_{k-1}*3^{k-1} $ terms ordered as they were in the $k-1$ group.

So as $64 < 100< 128$ so the 100th term is $3^6 + something$.

So the $1$st  term is $1$.  The second is $3$.  The $4$th is $3^2$ and the $64$ is $3^6$.  Then $64 + 32=96$th term is $3^6+3^5$ and $64+32 + 4=100$ is $3^6 + 3^5 + 3^2$.

**Then we give ourselves a giant dope slap to the head because this is clearly just binary representation.**

That is: If $n = \sum_{i = 0}^m b_i*2^i; b_i=\{0,1\}$ be the binary representation of $n$ then $a_n$  is $\sum_{i=0} b_i 3^i$ And that preserves order.

Answer (score 0):

Note that, if you represent the numbers in base $3$, that you get the numbers $1, 10, 11, 100 ...$ which are numbers in base $3$ such that each of the digits is either $1$ or $0$.

Therefore, we just need to find the $100$th number in the series and convert it from base $3$ to base $10$. This is equivalent to finding the $100$th binary number, which is $1100100$. Therefore, because we express this number in base 3 the $100$th term in the series is $1100100$ in base 3, which is $981$.

Comment: you are talking about base 3 then using binary ?

Comment: Andin  last line it should not be 11001003 but 1100100